# How to solve, in an elegant way and using JavaScript, the UTC problem, which subtracts a day when instantiating a Date in the format '2018-10-25'?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I'm working on legacy system and in DB the birthday is coming this way '1992-05-18' in json. I am using AngularJS and when applying the data binding of this variable in an `input type = "date"`, of an update form, it is necessary to instantiate a Date object. Like this:

```
//person.byrthday = '1992-04-26'
var person.birthday = new Date (person.birthday); 
// after person.byrthday = '1992-04-25T00:00:00.000Z'
```

How can I solve this problem through Front End in an elegant way, without "breaking" two way data binding?

I find myself in Brasil `UTC -03:00`

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use a library like Moment.js to handle dates.

Comment: If your offset is -0300, then given `new Date('1992-04-26')` the result will be a Date for '1992-04-26T00:00:00.000Z'. Treating it as UTC only shifts local dates by the host timezone offset (-0300 apparently), which will be '1992-04-25T21:00:00.000-0300'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem. A quick and dirty solution could be to leverage [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). You can convert the response from the API to a true date format this way.

If you don't want to use an additionally library, you can make a function to parse the date string. You can do the following to parse is to become a correct date:

```
var dateSplit = person.birthday.split('-');
var mydate = new Date(dateSplit[0], dateSplit[1] - 1, dateSplit[2]); 
person.birthday= mydate;
```

Take note that the month index starts at 0 (aka January=0). Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I suggest you use moment().add(1, 'days').calendar()?

Comment: @cpll—that will not fix the OP's issue.